# Imitate a swipe down gesture periodically

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, automation, gestures

There's an app that allows for monitoring of some specific process. This app gets locked every 5 minutes unless a screen activity is detected. The phone itself is not locked, the only app's interface is blocked. There's no way to configure the app's timeout to 10 or 30 or 60 minutes at all.

Is it possible to imitate a swipe down gesture periodically (for example, every 60 seconds)? I need it to run on Android 4.4.2.

I have seen AutoInput, but it appears it's not free.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! What do you want to accomplish while swiping down?

Comment: If you have root access, you can use Tasker and input command to do this. The app AutoInput might also be able to help here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Macrodoid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid). It offers 5 macros for free.

1. On the Triggers tab, under the Device Events section, select Screen On/Off then Screen On.
2. On the Actions tab, under the Device Actions section, select UI Interaction. Enable Macrodroid UI interaction accessibility option. Select UI Interaction, choose Gesture, then enter the X and Y values (X and Y screen coordinates: where to start and end the swipe).
3. Save the macro and give it a name.
4. Edit the macro. On the Actions tab, under the Conditions/Loops section, select Repeat actions, choose While 'conditions repeat. Add a condition (I selected Screen On, under the Screen and Speaker section, then Screen On/Off.
5. On the Actions tab, under the Macrodroid Specific section, select Wait Before Next Action, and set the time to 1 minute.
6. Click the up and down arrows on the Actions block, then move the items from steps 2 and 5 to be under the While/Do condition.
7. Save the macro. Click the 3-dot, then Test macro.

The macro will be like the image below:

[image]

When I tested it, I set the start values at X=100, Y=300 and the end values at X=500, Y=300 to simulate a swipe from left to right. The values on the steps described above should try to swipe the status bar down. I advise to change the X and Y values so they be based on your screen resolution and needs.

Comment: Thank you! I have installed the app and using your detailed reply created the macro. Will tune it for my needs.